# NHibernate disable all-delete-orphan

Tags: nhibernate

Application use NHibernate.
I Have object A that contains set of objects B.
I have cascade="all-delete-orphan" in my config file.
When I do changes in A object, then save, object B is also saving.
How to prevent saving B ? Is it possible to disable cascade for a moment ?
regards 
Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using IStatlessSession

> Operations performed using a stateless
>   session do not ever cascade to
>   associated instances. Collections are
>   ignored by a stateless session.
>   Operations performed via a stateless
>   session bypass Hibernate's event model
>   and interceptors. Stateless sessions
>   are vulnerable to data aliasing
>   effects, due to the lack of a
>   first-level cache. A stateless session
>   is a lower-level abstraction, much
>   closer to the underlying ADO.

Comment: In this case IStatlessSession helped me. Thank you.

Comment: Problem is when object A has to sets: B and C.
B is changed and C is not. 
when I Save A, I would like to save A and B and not to update C.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent cascade saving, you have to remove the attribute from the mapping. As mappings are built into session factory, there is no simple way to disable cascade temporarily.